# Rails belongs_to through solution with uniqueness scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have the following linked models:

```
class Event
   has_many :orders
   has_many :tickets, through: :orders
end

class Order
   belongs_to :event
   has_many :tickets
end

class Ticket
   belongs_to :order
   ? :event, ?: :order

   validates :name, uniqueness: { scope: :event }  
end
```

The problem is that whatever I fill in in the two `?` marks above, I get a different error when validating an instance of my Ticket model. Combinations I've tried:

- `delegate`/`to`: This is the cleanest solution. However, when validating a Ticket, the following error occurs: `no such column: tickets.event`
- `has_one`/`through`: This actually is bad practice as this touches the Event model upon saving. The error here is: `undefined method 'event_id' for #<Ticket:0x0000010787c730>`

At first sight, there doens't seem to be a way to cleanly check if the name on a ticket for a single event is unique or not. Am I missing something? Are there any clean solutions to this problem?

Thanks in advance,

Tom

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the `question mark line`. Instead try changing your validation to

`validates :name, uniqueness: true, scope: :event`

Your Ticket model should always `belong_to :event`. When the order is placed, the ticket should be associated to the event as well as the order. This means that you will need to add `event_id:integer` to your ticket model.